# Swift - Changing constant doesn't show error

Tags: swift

I'm reading a tutorial from a book. I can't attach the book here. In a chapter an `UIImage` constant is declared and its value is assigned in next lines. It is not a `var` neither `optional`. It runs successfully. How does it work?

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {         
  private func addAnnotations() {
    for business in businesses {
      guard let yelpCoordinate = business.location.coordinate else {
        continue
      }

      let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: yelpCoordinate.latitude,
                                              longitude: yelpCoordinate.longitude)
      let name = business.name
      let rating = business.rating
      let image:UIImage //Constant non-optional
      switch rating {
      case 0.0..<3.5:
        image = UIImage(named: "bad")!
      case 3.5..<4.0:
        image = UIImage(named: "meh")!
      case 4.0..<4.75:
        image = UIImage(named: "good")!
      case 4.75..<5.0:
        image = UIImage(named: "great")!
      default:
        image = UIImage(named: "bad")!
      }
      let annotation = BusinessMapViewModel(coordinate: coordinate,
                              name: name,
                              rating: rating, image: image)
      mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should know that it is perfectly fine in Swift to declare a variable and assign it a value on the next line, as long as you don't refer to that variable before it is assigned.

```
let a: Int
... // you can't use "a" here
a = 10 // OK!
```

Look at the switch statement after the variable declaration. A switch statement must be exhaustive, meaning that at least one case of it will be run. In this switch statement, every case has a single statement that assigns to `image`, and there are no `fallthrough`s. From these observations, both us and the compiler can conclude that `image` will be assigned (and assigned only once) after the switch statement, hence you can use it in the line:

```
let annotation = BusinessMapViewModel(coordinate: coordinate,
                              name: name,
                              rating: rating, image: image)
```

Comment: Is this behaviour introduced from any specific swift version? Or is it the default behaviour from the first release?

Comment: I started playing with Swift since Swift 2, and this behaviour exists at that time. I don't know about Swift 1 though. @arunsiva

Answer (score 2):

From the Swift 5.1 reference, [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html)

> When a constant declaration occurs in the context of a function or method, it can be initialized later, as long as it is guaranteed to have a value set before the first time its value is read.